# Вопрос по отображению вложенного списка

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

В чем у меня ошибка? Как мне получить желаемый список без повторного его копирования?

У меня есть код в нем я промежуточно получаю список b который отображается в памяти вот так:

```
[['  ', '  ', '  ', '  '], ['  ', '  ', '  ', '  '], ['  ', '  ', '  ', '  ']]
```

Далее у меня выполняется продолжение кода в котором я должен получить измененный список b:

```
[['  ', '  ', '  ', 5], ['  ', '  ', '  ', 6], ['  ', '  ', '  ', 7]]
```

Однако вместо него я получаю следующий (неправильный) список:

```
[['  ', '  ', '  ', 7], ['  ', '  ', '  ', 7], ['  ', '  ', '  ', 7]]
```

Вот исходный код:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]
f = [i for j in a for i in j]

q = len(f) ** 0.5
if q % 1 != 0.0:
    q = int(q) + 1
q = int(q)

v = ['  ' for i in range(q)]
n, b = [], []
for i in range(q - 1):
    n.append(f[i])
    b.append(v)
#b = [['  ', '  ', '  ', '  '], ['  ', '  ', '  ', '  '], ['  ', '  ', '  ', '  ']]
print(b)

k = 0
p = q

if k % 4 == 0:
    for i in b:
        i[q - 1:q] = [f[p]]
        p += 1

print(b)
```

Также хочу добавить что если убрать решетку то получится правильно, как мне сделать так чтобы правильно получалось без дублирования списка?

Comment: `b.append(v[:])`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрите, в чем дело.

Вы в список `b` положили не просто список с пробелами, вы положили туда **ссылку** на значение переменной `v`, причем не один раз, а целых четыре.

Поэтому, когда вы изменяете один список внутри списка `b`, то вы меняете значение переменной `v`, и, соответственно, автоматически меняются и три оставшихся списка (которые на самом деле - один и тот же).

Поэтому советую переписать вот эту часть:

```
v = [' ' for i in range(q)]
b = []
for i in range(q - 1):
    b.append(v)
```

Следующим образом:

```
b = []
for i in range(q - 1):
    b.append([' ' for i in range(q)])
```

**Дополнительно**

Можно также скопировать исходный список при помощи `copy`, в данном случае это решает проблему, но будьте аккуратны, если вдруг вы захотите сделать копию списка списков, то при поверхностном копировании через `copy` вложенные списки не пересоздаются, тогда уже поможет `deepcopy`, подробнее можно почитать [здесь](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/copy-python-deep-copy-shallow-copy/)

Вариант через `copy`:

```
from copy import copy

v = [' ' for i in range(q)]
b = []
for i in range(q - 1):
    b.append(v.copy())
```